# LVN_GETEMPTYMARKUP font

Tags: winapi, syslistview32

I have a subclass of `SYSLISTVIEW32`, and trap the `LVN_GETEMPTYMARKUP` [notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774833(v=vs.85).aspx). I return a string, and voila! I see the markup when my list view is empty:

[image]

How can I customise the font of the markup? Notably, my process is DPI aware and I am scaling all my fonts according to the current scale factor.

The list view empty markup is rendering at the wrong size on my 200% scaled display.

Comment: You have no control over how the ListView renders the markup text. If you don't like how it looks, don't use it. Owner-draw the ListView instead and draw your own text however you want

Comment: Thanks @RemyLebeau. The font style itself is fine, and if I wanted to change it owner-drawing would be fine. That the font is scaled wrong, and all I can do about that is owner-draw my control, makes me want to tear my hair out. Apple has been getting this stuff right for years, yet Windows support for HiDPI has been through how many revisions? And still there are niggles like this. Thanks for the confirmation.